# Prove that there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that $\frac {2^{6n}-4}{6n-1}$ is equal to an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that there are infinitely many  integers $n$ such that $\frac {2^{6n}-4}{6n-1}$ is equal to an integer

I am struggling with this qustion. Could you walk me through it?

Comment: You have a mismatched number of parentheses in your question title and based on how badly it is written and context, it seems likely that you mean for all of $6n-1$ to be in the denominator rather than only $6n$.  So... confirm... are you asking to show there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that $\dfrac{2^{6n}-4}{6n-1}$ is an integer?  Or something else?

Comment: Have you tried any examples?  If you do, a simple pattern should emerge quite quickly.

Comment: Yes JMoravitz it is the equation that you have written.

Comment: Yes JMoravitz it is the equation that you have written.

Comment: I don't know where to begin

Comment: Always begin with examples.  You can do $n≤3$  by hand, but you'll want a computer to check examples for even fairly small $n$. Be sure to go far enough to get a few fails (cases where the quotient is not an integer).   Keep a list of $n, 2^{6n}-4,6n-1$ and record which ones work and which ones fail.  You should spot a pattern quite quickly and it's not difficult to prove enough to settle the given question.

Comment: Is there a way to prove it without a computer?

Comment: Number theory is based on examples...you should be able to work with simple expressions like these.  To be clear, however:  the computer won't help you with the proof.  All it will do is to suggest a pattern which you must then prove.  If you can guess a useful pattern without examples, that would work too.  But I recommend looking at examples.

Comment: **Hint** $\ 6n\!-\!1 = p\,$ prime $\,\Rightarrow\, 2^{\large 6n}\!\equiv 2^{\large p+1}\!\equiv 2^{\large 2}\,\color{#c00}{2^{\large p-1}}\!\equiv 4\,$ by little $\rm\color{#c00}{Fermat}$. Thus $\,6n\!-\!1\mid 2^{\large 6n}\!-4$. But there are infintely many primes of the form $\,6n\!-\!1\,$ by a simple generalization of Euclid's famous one-line proof (we've   tens if not hundreds of posts on this, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1318537/242); for generalizations see  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11330/dirichlets-theorem-on-primes-in-arithmetic-progression)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method. First one can start by noticing the similarity in $6n-1$ and $6n$ in the exponent. Factor out a $2$ from the numerator to get
$$2 * \frac{2^{6n-1} - 2}{6n-1}$$
The question at hand is equivalent to asking if
$$2^{6n-1} - 2 \equiv 0 \mod 6n-1$$
(this means the numerator is divisible by the denominator. modular arithmetic is useful in number theory problems so it would be helpful to become familiar with it). Essentially, if $a \equiv b \mod n$, then $a - b$ is divisible by $n$. Here, all this is saying is that $(2^{6n-1} - 2) - 0 = 2^{6n-1} - 2$ is divisible by $6n-1$, which is equivalent to what you are trying to prove. There is a famous theorem called Euler's theorem, which states that $a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$ if $n$ is coprime to $a$, where $\phi(n)$ is the number of integers less than $n$ coprime to $n$. You can read about this function [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). Let $a = 2$ and $n = 6n-1$ (which are trivially coprime, as one is even and the other is odd). According to Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions, $6n-1$ contains infinitely many primes. Let $n$ be any arbitrary integer such that $6n-1$ is prime, then
$$2^{\phi(6n-1)} \equiv 2^{6n-2} \equiv 1 \mod 6n-1$$
or
$$2^{6n-1} \equiv 2 \mod 6n-1$$
proving that $2^{6n-1} - 2 \equiv 0 \mod 6n-1$ for infinitely many $n$. A lot of useful results help with problems like this when they are translated into modular arithmetic, so I would really encourage reading about it.

Comment: It would be intersting to see directly there are infinitely primes of form $6n-1$. :)

Comment: Dirichlet is a sledgehammer. Euclid's famous one-line proof easily generalizes to show that there are infinitely many primes of the form $\,6n-1.\,$ We probably have tens if not hundreds of posts on this, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1318537/242).  For generalizations see the links [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11330/dirichlets-theorem-on-primes-in-arithmetic-progression).

Comment: Since you rely on the infinitude of primes of the form $6n-1$, you might have extracted a factor of $4$ rather than $2$ and then simply invoked Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: @Keth That was lllready mentioned in [a comment on the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3646810/prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-integers-n-such-that-frac-26n-46n?noredirect=1#comment7494685_3646810).